# Add extra parameters to each AFMultipartFormData

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I want to send an array of images to the server and on each image within the array I want to add parametrs to the call. How can I do this? Curently I can only add it to the whole request.

```
     [self POST:@"api/sendimage"  parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData
                                    name:@"files"
                                fileName:@"file_1" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
         [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData
                                     name:@"files"
                                 fileName:@"file_2" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];


        // etc.
    } success:[self successBlock:progressBackground] failure:[self failBlock:progressBackground]];
```

Comment: I cant change server side :(

Answer (score 0):

That is my project's solution. Can you try this?

```
  UIImage *img1 = [UIImage new];
  UIImage *img2 = [UIImage new];

  NSArray *photo = @[img1,img2]; 

  AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
  manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

  NSString *path = @"api/sendimage";

  NSMutableDictionary *parameters;

  parameters = [@{
          @"Token" : @"123"
  } mutableCopy];

  [manager POST:path parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id <AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

      if ( photo.count ) {
          [photo enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIImage *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

              NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(obj,0.6);
              [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", arc4random() % 99999] fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", arc4random() % 99999]] mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];

          }];

      }

  } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

      success();
  } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
      failure();
  }];
```